# Invalid label resource request on Amazon EMR when trying to initialize a SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I got this error when trying to run the spark-shell on Amazon EMR

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidLabelResourceRequestException: Invalid label resource request, cluster do not contain , label= CORE
```

I have restarted all YARN services and the issue remains. Can anyone help me with this?

Below is the full stack trace:

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidLabelResourceRequestException: Invalid label resource request, cluster do not contain , label= CORE
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.checkQueueLabelInLabelManager(SchedulerUtils.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.normalizeAndValidateRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:257)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.normalizeAndValidateRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.validateAndCreateResourceRequest(RMAppManager.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.createAndPopulateNewRMApp(RMAppManager.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:257)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:499)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:447)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:850)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:793)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2489)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateYarnException(RPCUtil.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:276)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:346)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.submitApplication(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.submitApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:258)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:501)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:45)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:49)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietRun$1.apply(IMain.scala:231)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietRun$1.apply(IMain.scala:231)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:221)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:199)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$mumly$1.apply(ILoop.scala:189)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:221)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.mumly(ILoop.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:235)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:282)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runClosure(SparkILoop.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: What cluster configuration do you have (core, task, master nodes)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Finally, I found the solution. It seems that the node label of the yarn node was lost for some reason. I put it back with the following command:

```sudo -u yarn yarn rmadmin -addToClusterNodeLabels "CORE(exclusive=false))"```